# Hide filters in ASP.NET Dynamic Data

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-dynamic-data

Using ASP.NET with Dynamic Data my page looks like:

[image]

I want to hide the drop-down lists `Invoicing Complete` and `Restricted Hours` at the top of the page. I have made them invisible from the table by using:

```
[HideColumnIn(PageTemplate.ListDetails, PageTemplate.List)]
[ReadOnlyColumnIn(PageTemplate.Edit)]
[DisplayName("Invoicing Complete")]
public object Invoicing_Complete { get; set; }
```

but they are still appearing at the top, as a drop-down. 
I can't use `[ScaffoldColumn(false)]` as that hides it entirely and I need the user to view it from `Edit.aspx` and `Insert.aspx` pages.

Please advise.

EDIT: Any one have any ideas? Can't seem to find out how to do this...Did I explain the Q properly?

Answer (score 3):

John, **HideColumnIn** and **ReadOnlyColumnIn** are attributes for hide *Columns* not *Filters* (ForeignKey filters).

You can solve this problem using a several ways.

The first way, if you are using *.NET Framework 4.5* or *.NET Framework 4* you may use the **AutoGenerateFilter Property** of **DisplayAttribute**. For example,

```
[Display(Name = "Invoicing Complete", AutoGenerateFilter = false)]
```

More information you can find on [AutoGenerateFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayattribute.autogeneratefilter%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

The second way is to create new Attribute (like **HideColumnIn**) and then change Code-Behind for **ForeignKey** filter.

Some example:

**HideFilterAttribute.cs**

```
using System;

namespace iSite.Classes.Attributes
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
    public class HideFilterAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public Boolean Hide { get; private set; }

        public HideFilterAttribute(Boolean hide)
        {
            this.Hide = hide;
        }

        // default
        public static HideFilterAttribute Default =
            new HideFilterAttribute(false);
    }
}
```

**ForeignKey.ascx.cs**

```
public partial class ForeignKeyFilter : System.Web.DynamicData.QueryableFilterUserControl
{
        protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                string initialValue = DefaultValue;
                if (initialValue == null && Column.Attributes.OfType<HideFilterAttribute>().DefaultIfEmpty(HideFilterAttribute.Default).First().Hide)
                {
                        this.NamingContainer.Visible = false;
                }
                else
                {
                        PopulateListControl(DropDownList1);
                        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(initialValue))
                        {
                                ListItem li = new ListItem();
                                li = DropDownList1.Items.FindByValue(initialValue);
                                DropDownList1.Items.Clear();
                                DropDownList1.Items.Add(li);
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

The third and the fourth ways are without DynamicData approach. You can use custom Filter for this column and hide DropDownList control via **Visible** property. And also you can hide DropDownList control via jQuery library.

Comment: +1 And should be marked as Answer. @Konstantin K was dead on with his "second way" approach.  We had a problem with 10,000+ items listed in DDLs and needed to hide them.  Previously, we `[Display(AutoGenerateFilter = false)]` which actually broke those lists pages because it ignored the key filter if specified in the querystring.  Going with his 2nd approach was perfect.